# How to use GREP command to read more then one line in file

Tags: linux, grep

I am stumped.  How can I use the GREP command to read more then one line in a file.  this is what I have worked on so far but only reads one line in file.  If I add another line that's when it says can't read ....  I am using Linux shell.  I have been trying to research this for the past 2 days and still nothing.  Any help would be welcomed. Thanks.

```
(

echo;echo -ne "Checking Firewall INPUT chain for entry ... ";

if ! iptables -vnL INPUT | grep `cat $_file` >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Not Found!"

    for IP in `cat $_scriptpath/tmp/badip.cache`
   do

    iptables -A INPUT -s $IP -j badipblock

   done

    echo External IP : $IP has been banned! $_DATE > $_scriptpath/log/badip_fw_$_DATE.log
else
echo "Entry already exists"
fi
echo;

)
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: ...and as an aside, all-caps variable names are specified for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell, whereas names containing lowercase characters are reserved for application use -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an existing environment variable will overwrite the latter.

Comment: (...and another aside, *both* `echo -e` and `echo -n` are best avoided. See the RATIONALE and APPLICATION USAGE sections of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)).

Comment: ...and as another aside? Don't reinvent the wheel. Reliable, robust, solid iptables-management tools have existed for ages. Use something written by folks who know what they're doing -- personally, I suggest [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/).

Answer (score 2):

#### How to read a list of patterns to match from a file in grep

```
grep -f "$_file"
```

...will treat each line of `$_file` as a pattern, and will match *any* of those patterns. (The usual flags can be used to modify how those patterns are interpreted -- `-E` for ERE, `-F` for fixed strings, etc).

---

#### Why the original code failed

The immediate cause is this:

```
grep `cat $_file`
```

In this apparently-innocuous code, you're actually doing the following:

- Splitting the contents of the variable `$_file` on the characters found in the shell setting `IFS` (by default spaces, tabs and newlines) into more than one word
- Treating each of those words as a separate glob expression; if any *can* be parsed as a glob, then replacing it with one word for each matching entry on the local filesystem.
- Passing the words resulting from *that* stage each as a separate argument to `cat`.
- Letting `cat` try to open a file named for each such word (unless they start with dashes, in which case it would treat them as option flags) and concatenate together their output.
- Capturing that concatenated output, string-splitting it again (as above), glob-expanding it again (as above), and then appending the resulting words to the command line for `grep`

...so, then, what does that do? Let's say that the output from `cat` only evaluates to one word, `foo`:

```
grep foo
```

...so, we're looking for `foo` in our stdin streams. Let's say, by contrast, that it evaluates to two words, `foo` and `bar`:

```
grep foo bar
```

This is doing something **entirely different**: It's treating `foo` as a string to search for -- but it's treating `bar` as the name of the file to search in, ignoring anything which you piped as stdin.

---

Some references to follow going forward:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?")
- [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)